# List of sheet_names then read under a condition

Tags: python, excel

What I'm trying to do, I think I'm close to, is to read an excel file, create a list of all sheet_names found in the file, and then if the name contains "Activity" then read it and then concatenate it in a data frame. I would appreciate your expertise on this matter.

```
df_ac = pd.DataFrame()

wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\bosuna\OneDrive\Desktop" + '\\' + ffile, read_only=True)
sheets = [s for s in wb if "Activity" in wb]

for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\bosuna\OneDrive\Desktop" + '\\' + ffile, sheet_name=sheet, read_only=True)
    df_ac = pd.concat([df, df_ac], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: please elaborate on the *condition* that you are using to select sheet names, as it seems to be different than what your code suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use append as well instead of concat..

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = pd.ExcelFile('name of file.xlsx')
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()


for sheet in x1.sheet_names:  # iterate through sheet name
    if 'ACTIVITY' in sheet:  # check wether activity is present in sheet name
       df = pd.read_excel('name of file.xlsx',sheet_name = sheet)
       empty_df = empty_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the list comprehension (line 4), you are checking for `"Activity"` in `wb`, instead of `s` (sheet name)

This is the equivalent of only iterating over *all* sheets if *one* of them is "Activity".

From what I understand, the **expected behaviour** is to only read a sheet, if the sheet name *itself* contains the phrase "Activity", and this, is different from the **actual behaviour**.

Replace the 4th line with this

```py
sheets = [s for s in wb if "Activity" in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood, but I'm assuming you are trying to load the "Activity" sheet into a panda dataframe if it exists within the workbook. If that is the case I propose the following solution:

```
wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\bosuna\OneDrive\Desktop" + '\\' + ffile, read_only=True)
if 'Activity' in wb.sheetnames:
    df = pd.DataFrame(wb['Activity' ].values)
```